# Pattern match on value of Map's key in elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to pattern match on the value of a key in a map

```
  def handle_in("new_message", payload, socket) do
    case payload.message do
      "hello" -> broadcast! socket, "new_message", payload
    end

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

`[error] GenServer #PID<0.378.0> terminating
** (KeyError) key :message not found in: %{"message" => "hello", "name" => "x"}
    (chatroom) web/channels/lobby_channel.ex:9: Chatroom.LobbyChannel.handle_in/3
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:226: anonymous fn/4 in Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:601: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:667: :gen_server.handle_msg/5`

when I send the payload of `%{"message" => "hello", "name" => "x"}`, that error happens, or for any other message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your key here is `"message"` not `:message`. Use: `payload["message"]`

```
  def handle_in("new_message", payload, socket) do
    case payload["message"] do
      "hello" -> broadcast! socket, "new_message", payload
    end

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

---

You can also do this:

```
  def handle_in("new_message", %{"message" => message}, socket) do
    case message do
      # ...
  end
```